# Leashing etiquette

Tags: league-of-legends

I am wondering what is the proper leashing etiquette since I have two different trains of thought plus other variants.  Here are the possible permutation groups:

1. before or after the jungler
2. the main (e.g. head golem) or the supporting
3. once/twice and leave or until the jungler is ready to smite/kill or signal you to leave

So the permutations possible are

1. Hit the main once/twice and leave before the jungler
2. Hit the main once/twice and leave after the jungler
3. Hit the extras once/twice and leave before the jungler
4. Hit the extras once/twice and leave after the jungler
5. Hit the main until signaled to leave (i.e. head golem) and leave before the jungler
6. Hit the main until signaled to leave (i.e. head golem) and leave after the jungler
7. Hit the extras until signaled to leave (i.e. head golem) and leave before the jungler
8. Hit the extras until signaled to leave (i.e. head golem) and leave after the jungler

Comment: You dont want to be around when the monster(s) actually die - Make sure you're not leaching xp from the jungler

Comment: @BenCraig Are you sure this still happens? I know for a fact that Gromp only gives exp to the killer, but I don't know about the other camps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually it depends on the current meta, but right now it's pretty straightforward.  There are 2 scenarios.

1) If they smite right away, get it to at least under 300 and as far as 200 hp then leave.

2) If they hold smite get it under at least under 600 and as far as 500 hp before leaving.

Comment: Do we attack before or after the jungler starts attacking?

Comment: Soon as it spawns.

Comment: ok I'll try this one

Answer (score 2):

General etiquette is to attack the main monster until it's less than two (jungler) AAs away from death. As a toplane, however, you should help as much as you can, but leave so that you at least recieve EXP for every minion in your lane.

How much you leash should however depend on how you want to play your lane as well as who your jungler is:

 
If you have a high-sustain jungler, then it won't matter to much at what point you leave. If you have a bad sustain / clearing jungler like Twitch, helping him a bit extra early on, can make a vast difference. Fiddlesticks will on the other hand not require such help.

Oftentimes if I play an aggressive lane, such as Janna & Caitlyn down bot, I'll want to leave slighly earlier as Caitlyn (the ADC) to soak up the EXP and push the lane for an early level 2. And I will ask my support to stay for a couple of extra autos to compensate for me leaving as well as an extra shield onto the jungler.
*IMO when the botlane leashes it would be customary for the ADC to leave after a couple of hits, and the support staying for a couple of more.*

Additional Notes:
Don't be afraid to tank the first auto from the monster. You'll regenerate to full hp before getting into your lane.

Comment: Well done answer.  IF you combine the notes on HP's from the other answer and this its darned near perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Heimerdinger, don't offer to leash. Your turrets are still live after you leave, and there's a good chance that your turret will steal the buff. its happened often enough for me not to leash, plus heimer mid MUST get 3 turrets built to have a chance.

Comment: No.  This depends on early or late smite and the time you time your leaving so that the turrets power down.